# thingsboard on Amazon EC2 does not show data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, thingsboard

I have installed thingsboard on Amazon EC2. The code on the device works because I can upload data to the live demo server. And I think that the upload to AWS works as well because I can download data via Rest API with R from AWS. However, thingsboard does not show the data in the client attributes or latest telemetry. Can this be an issue with thingsboard UI connecting the EC2 volume (EBS)?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to websockets blocked in your local network/provider. You need to install HTTPS proxy on the same server and make sure you serve https. In that case websockets will not be blocked.